# Advanced Sort in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, sorting

I need to amend a system built in cakePHP to change the sort order from alphabetical on a field to alphabetical on the same field but minus the first character (whilst still displaying the entire field).

So essentially if they had.. `a1, a3, b2, b4` the sort order would be `a1, b2, a3, b4`

The code currently sorts based on `find()` is there a way I can force this type of sort into it or do I need to write some type of custom query?

Comment: do you need this sort in a paginated list?

Comment: No, I won't need it paginated - the end results are going into a select box.

Comment: so maybe its better to sort it in PHP because the ORDER clause could slow your query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well.. you have two options:

Sort it using php after the query. You could use [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). But this wont work if you want to paginate the results

Or you could modify the find query to something like this:

```
$this->MyModel->find('all',array(... ,'order'=>'SUBSTRING(MyTable.sortfield,2) ASC'));
```

the idea is to generate a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `MyTable` WHERE ... ORDER BY SUBSTRING(sortfield,2);
```

Good Luck